# Cloudbees & Play! is only deploying in dev mode

Tags: playframework

I have a Play! application in which the `application.conf` file has some attributes that are prefixed with `%production`, these are to define that I wish for different configurations when running in production rather than development. But when I use the cloudbees module from the command line `play bees:app:deploy`, when it does it's work it says compiling in DEV mode. which means it's ignoring my `%production` attributes, i've checked and I do have an attribute which uses `%production` to set that its in prod rather than dev mode.

I've also tried replacing all instances of `%production` in my conf to use instead `%bees, %prod and %cloudbees`. But these prefixes are also ignored. Is there a way for me to deploy my cloudbees application in production mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use the cloudbees module but I think you're missing the production option
Try adding it

```
play bees:app:deploy --%production
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [this tutorial](http://www.devinprogress.info/2011/02/play-framework-deploy-to-cloudbeescom.html).

(*Disclaimer: I haven't tried it. If I could I would rather comment than give a possibly useless answer.*)

Comment: Wish I had 15 rep to 1up you, this is a great solution, and actually the python files in the cloudbees module seem to be doing something similar maybe once I read over them and compare to this tutorial I'll find my final solution(Or could edit the python files to a solution)) Though it's probably more likely I'm doing something wrong rather than their code.